# How to Strongly Name an Assembly so that it has a Public Key Token

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am trying to create a Project Template Wizard.  For that I need a strongly named Assembly with a Public Key token.

I went here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123.aspx and followed the steps.

I end up with a .pfx file in my assembly.  But when I clean and build the dll does not have a Public Key Token on it.

(I verified via running 'sn -t EventWizard.dll'  and I got this as a result:

> Failed to convert key to token -- The public key for assembly '(null)' was invalid.

So I don't think I am getting a Public Key Token.  How can I get one?

**Update:** Here is my Signing Tab:

[image: Signing Screenshot]

Comment: What is selected in the dropdown under Signing?

Comment: @SLaks - I added a screenshot.

Comment: That should work; I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: @SLaks, thanks for the naming update...  I updated the question to reflect.

Comment: @SLaks, Weird that it does not work... I hopped I was missing a certificate or something.

Comment: Are you sure you properly rebuilt it and checked the right file?

Comment: @SLaks - sadly yes.  I cleaned and verified the file was gone (and ran SN.exe and verified that it said the file was not there).  I then did a rebuild and ran SN.exe and it gave the same message that I indicated in my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it was strongly named after all.  But the sn.exe tool needed to be used in a different way to see the value I was looking for (PublicKeyToken).

If I ran this:

```
sn -e EventWizard.dll temp.txt
sn -t temp.txt
```

Then it worked just fine.

Answer (score 30):

I also faced with this.

Solution is very simple - arguments are case sensitive.

```
sn -T <yourassembly.dll>
```

Answer (score 7):

I have also faced problems with this.

Solution is very simple - arguments are case sensitive.

```
//Does not work
sn -t yourassembly.dll

//Works
sn -T yourassembly.dll
```

Answer (score 6):

Found a solution at [InternalsVisibleTo with Strong-Type Assemblies](http://geekswithblogs.net/AnneBougie/archive/2008/10/01/internalsvisibleto-with-strongly-type-assemblies.aspx)

Go to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools (Or where ever sn.exe is)

```
sn -p MyKey.snk MyKey.PublicKeyOnly.snk
```

This copies over the public key to a new file

```
sn -tp MyKey.PublicKeyOnly.snk
```

this will output in something like:
Public key is
0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100cfb8bc23b86a08
e70d021dd53d3b0293e716e71015870bdcc58a0231a4228618851a83e06077f5a44f42beb2baf3
56ad2d344521a96b0081ed0f25f9227523e3625eda524efe1cf2e1e5e41f3693a76ec52347684b
8129a4bb2d5fc49681adf33da0eecc4f81f011af4539d12abe1b4e760b5ce32d766db1012d4402
8381f0b4

Public key token is 2ff2b71993eeff95

Copy the public key value and update the InternalsVisibleTo:

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProject.Domain.Tests, PublicKey=
0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100cfb8bc23b86a08
e70d021dd53d3b0293e716e71015870bdcc58a0231a4228618851a83e06077f5a44f42beb2baf3
56ad2d344521a96b0081ed0f25f9227523e3625eda524efe1cf2e1e5e41f3693a76ec52347684b
8129a4bb2d5fc49681adf33da0eecc4f81f011af4539d12abe1b4e760b5ce32d766db1012d4402
8381f0b4")]