# Strong name is not created correctly for .NET Core assembly

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2022, strongname, strong-named-key

I am trying to give a strong name to a .NET Core assembly in Visual Studio 2022 (using the standard instructions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/sign-strong-name)

I have created a `.snk` file using command `sn -k mykey.snk`. In the properties of my project under "Strong Naming", I checked "Sign the assembly" and chose the `mykey.snk` file.

After building the project to `MyLib.dll`, I wanted to check that it has a strong name, but running command `sn -tp MyLib.dll` shows the following message:

> Failed to convert key to token -- Invalid assembly public key.

I tried the same flow on assembly in .NET Core 6, 7 and 2.1 - same result.

Is it a bug, or did I miss something? What is the correct way to give a strong name to .NET Core assembly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763916/how-to-strongly-name-an-assembly-so-that-it-has-a-public-key-token